# socket.emit only works after recursive function(implemented using requestAnimationFrame) is terminated

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, express, socket.io

I'm trying to infinitely send array to my server from the client side using a recursive function and get response from my server accordingly, however the messages from my server dont come back in real time, it is only after the recursive function is terminated the messages from the server are sent.

I'm not sure whether it's the problem with the code at the client side or the server side. Thanks in advance.

This is my server.js script.

```js
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

var https = require('https').createServer(sslOptions, app);
var io = require('socket.io')(https);

const port = 8080;
const host = "x.x.x.x"; // my host server IP address

io.on('connection', (socket) => {
  console.log('a user connected');
  socket.on('predict', (data)=>{
  
      // this line is executed after recursive function at client side is stopped
      console.log("socket from client");
      
      // this line is executed after after recursive function at client side is stopped
      socket.emit('result', { "message": "hello world from server"});
  });
});


https.listen(port, host);
```

This is my app.component.ts script.

```js
// this is my recursive function
    detectFromVideoFrame = (model, video, stop_detecting) => {
     
    this.detect(video).then(predictions => { 

      // stop recursive loop if stop_detecting == true
      if(!(this.stop_detecting)){

        requestAnimationFrame(() => {
          this.detectFromVideoFrame(model, video, stop_detecting);
        });
      }
    }, (error) => {
      console.error(error)
    });
  };
```

```js
this.dataService.setupSocketConnection();

// these two lines are in this.detect function
this.dataService.getTFprediction(imageTensorArr);
      
this.dataService.onNewMessage().subscribe(msg => {
  console.log('got a msg: ', msg);
});
```

This is my service.ts script

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import * as io from 'socket.io-client';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class DataService {
  private socket: SocketIOClient.Socket;

  constructor() {}
  setupSocketConnection() {
    this.socket = io('https://x.x.x.x:8080');
    this.socket.on('connect', function () {
      console.log("socket connected on client side");
    });
  }

  getTFprediction(videoArray){
  
    // this line is executed normally each time this function is called at the app.component.ts script
    console.log("check connection: ", this.socket.connected);
    
    // I'm not sure when is this line executed
    this.socket.emit('predict', { "data": videoArray } )
  }

  onNewMessage() {
    return Observable.create(observer => {
      this.socket.on('result', msg => {
        console.log(msg.message);
        observer.next(msg);
      });
    });
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this is the problem:

```js
  onNewMessage() {
    return Observable.create(observer => {
      this.socket.on('result', msg => {
        console.log(msg.message);
        observer.next(msg);
      });
    });
  }
```

The socket event handler is something you would want to initialize while creating the socketio client, not when the observable is subscribed to.

I would recommend doing it as below:

```js
  resultSubject = new Subject();

  setupSocketConnection() {
    this.socket = io('https://x.x.x.x:8080');
    this.socket.on('connect', function () {
      console.log("socket connected on client side");
    });

    this.socket.on('result', (event) => {
      this.resultSubject.next(event);
    });
  }
```

In app.component

```js
class AppComponent {
  constructor(private dataService: DataService) {}

  this.dataService.resultSubject
      .subscribe((message) => {
        console.log('received from socket: ', message);
      });
}
```